# Getting website image generated by javascript (basically is a captcha)

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, captcha

I want to get this [captcha](https://captcha.com/demos/features/captcha-demo.aspx) into a picturebox, in vb.
The objective is to access a website and send the captcha image to the program, in order for the user to write the captcha text in a TextField and access the site contents.

Is it possible?? XD
the code i already have is bellow (its working but it does not get the captcha image :( )
thx everyone i appreciate all the help

```
Private Sub txtFileURL_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtFileURL.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim fileURL As String = txtFileURL.Text
        Dim fileName As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(fileURL)

        Dim saveFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        Dim saveFullPath As String = saveFolder + "\" + fileName

        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(fileURL, saveFullPath)
            MsgBox("Saved in Desktop!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
            file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\test.txt", True)
            file.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            file.Close()
    End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "its working but it does not get the captcha image"...if it's not doing what you wanted then how can you say it's working? Anyway, what goes wrong? Is an exception occurring? I see you are catching and suppressing exceptions without logging them, so you have no real way to determine the problem, except by stepping through with a debugger and stopping in the Catch block to examine the exception (but first you'd have to declare it). Suppressing unexpected errors like this is a horrible anti-pattern which should be avoided - it makes troubleshooting very hard. _at least_ log the exception.

Comment: with that code above the only thing I can't do is download a generated image (captcha) and that's what I want the program to do.
I updated the code sry for the catch.
Here is the exception:


'www.captcha.com/demos/features/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&c=c_captchademo_samplecaptcha&t=efccb902d2fe4059840ee492ca67da35' is not a valid remote file address. A valid address must include a protocol, path, and file name.
Parameter Name: address

Comment: Well, as mentioned in the error, the protocol is missing from your URL. Try adding `http://` (or `https://`, whichever it is) to the beginning of your URL string. The code has no idea which of those (or any other) protocols to use when making the download request.

Comment: OMG I cant believe! It was so easy. Adding http://  solved the problem. Even I feel bad for being so easy.
THX ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by: [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson)

Well, as mentioned in the error, the protocol is missing from your URL. Try adding http:// (or https://, whichever it is) to the beginning of your URL string. The code has no idea which of those (or any other) protocols to use when making the download request.